# C# MVC How to pass the button value back to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the button value back to controller when the user click on the button. I had search online for a few ways but all cant get the result. Can anyone help on this? thank you.

the current result is:

[image]

I want to replace the button time value to "Time result..."

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Timeline()
{
    List<String> token = new List<string>();
    ViewBag.Date = "Time result......";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string query = " SELECT TakenDate FROM ReferenceWound WHERE NRIC = '" + "S2686621B" + "' AND NurseInCharge = '" + User_Nurse + "'";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    token.Add(sdr["TakenDate"].ToString());
                }
            }

            var datetaken = new List<PatientModel>();

            foreach(var date in token)
            {
                datetaken.Add(new PatientModel()
                {
                    Date = date
                });
            }
            con.Close();

            return View(datetaken);
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class PatientModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string PatientNRIC { get; set; }

    public string NurseInCharge { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> PatientList { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Timeline", "DashBoard", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var dest in Model)
            {
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">@dest.Date</td>
            }
        </tr>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var dest in Model)
            {
                <td style="width: 100px; text-align: center;"><input type="submit" value="@dest.Date" /></td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            }
        </tr>
    </table>
}

@ViewBag.Date
```

Comment: so you want to get value returned from sql query back in view ?

Comment: Why have you made property `Date` typeof `string` when it appears to be `DateTime`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a Name attribute to your button:

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" value="@dest.Date" />
```

Create an action method to accept the button's POST request, passing in the view's FormCollection:

```
public ActionResult Timeline(FormCollection form)
{
     var dest = form["btnSubmit"]; // access the value here
}
```

This approach allows you to access all the controls in the view's Form.

Comment: The `id` attribute is not necessary (a form only posts back name/value pairs)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for you help. I get the results. Thanks a lot/

Comment: No problem, please remember to mark the correct Answer.

Answer (score 4):

Simplifying your example

Model

```
public class Patient
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var p1 = new Patient { date = DateTime.Now };
            var p2 = new Patient { date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) };
            var listOfPatients = new List<Patient>();
            listOfPatients.Add(p1);
            listOfPatients.Add(p2);
            return View(listOfPatients);
        }

        public ActionResult Timeline(DateTime date)
        {
            return Content(date.ToString());
        }

    }
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<experiment.Models.Patient>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Timeline", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Patient</legend>
        @foreach(var p in Model)
        {
            <button type="submit" name="date" value="@p.date">@p.date</button>
        }
    </fieldset>
}
```

Tested in ASP.NET MVC 4

Comment: I assumed that if my button had an "id" attribute set that it would work, but I guess you need a "name" attribute. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could give your button a name:

```
<input type="submit" name="myButton" value="@dest.Date" />
```

and then your controller action could take it as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Timeline(string myButton)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: OP's image suggests the value is `DateTime` in which case the parameter can be `DateTime myButton`